# I am facing one issue after upgrade the jquery jqgrid to 4.13.5 .I want to colspan 2 to cellattr and it is not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

`cellattr : dashboardView.handleColSpan

handleColSpan : function(rowId, value, rowObject, colModel, arrData) {

```
    var pos = Utils.getInt(rowId.replace('jqg', ''));
    // var pos = Utils.getInt(rowId);
    if (!isNaN(pos) && (pos % 8 === 1) && Utils.isNotBlank(value)){
    // if ((pos === 1 && Utils.isNotBlank(value))) {
        return 'colspan=2';
    } else if (!isNaN(pos) && (pos % 8 === 1)) {
        return " style=display:none; ";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

this code is working find. But when it interact with grid file, the colspan is not getting added to the table cell

Renewal  like this the colspan should be added`

Comment: Just console.log the conditions and parameters to see whet is happen when you "interact" with grid file.